# Wygwam source button

Tags: wygwam, admin

i'm using the wygwam editor and i'd like to use the source button/option with my admin account. but the source button should not be visible/usable for other members.

any idea how to do that?

thanks!

Comment: Posts on StackExchange should include a very specific and answerable question. Please also see the 'What to include in your question" section of the FAQ & edit your post to include more information: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wygwam Super Admin Source](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wygwam-super-admin-source) does exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes, tried that before but this extension doesn`t seem to work with EE 2, latest version. It won´t show up at the extensions tab after installing. Is there a similar Extension?

Comment: @user2415, the Wygwam Super Admin Source extension works fine and is definitely the way to go. You just need to make sure that the folder you put into third_party is exactly named `wygwam_super_admin_source` -- if you download it from Github you may need to rename it!